# how does sas calculates the value of a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sas, case, stat

I don't understand how sas calculates the value for PATIENT , I've looked everywhere but there seems to be no documentation for how sas, calculates the formulas in the case parenthesis, I only know that when the value of
PATIENT is even the CASE expression has a Boolean result of 1 , 0 or 2, but I just don't see how to get the value out of the expression, could someone please explain me?

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE TESTMED AS
 SELECT PATIENT,
 CASE ((PATIENT/2 = INT(PATIENT/2)) +
 (PATIENT = .))
 WHEN 1 THEN 'Med A' WHEN 0 THEN
 'Med B' ELSE 'Error' END AS DOSEGRP
 LENGTH=5
 FROM VITALS
 ORDER BY PATIENT;
QUIT;
```

Comment: I think you should have a MySQL error because of this part `(PATIENT = .)` !? - And in MySQL `(1 = 1)` is equal to `1` ;).

Comment: can you please provide us some patient values? I can't see any error in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any error.

if patient could be . 0 1 2 this will be (first expression + second expression):

```
0 ---> {0=0}true(1) + {patient=.} false(0) = 1
1 ---> {0.5=0}false(0) + {patient=.} false(0) = 0
2 ---> {1=1}true(1) +{patient=.} false(0) = 1
. ---> {.=.} true(1) + {patient=.} true(1) = 2
```

If you want to see the result of that boolean expression you can simply use:

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE TESTMED AS
 SELECT patient, 
     ((PATIENT/2 = INT(PATIENT/2)) + (PATIENT = .))  AS result
 LENGTH=5
 FROM VITALS
 ORDER BY PATIENT;
QUIT;
```

and you will see that the results are correct.
So your boolean expression could assume only 3 values:

```
(1=0+1)
(0=0+0)
(2=1+1)

When 0 you assign MEDA;
When 1 you assign MEDB;
When 2 you assign ERROR;
```

And ERROR is assigned for missing values.

```
1st expression:
{missing/2=missing} = {int(missing)=missing} [errors are reported as missing]
missing=missing ---> true ---> 1

2nd expression:
missing=missing ---> true ---> 1

result:
1+1=2 ---> ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS evaluates boolean expressions to 1 (true) or 0 (false).  So your expressions is the sum of two of these. So the possible answers are 0, 1 or 2.

The first expression, `(PATIENT/2 = INT(PATIENT/2))`, will be true when PATIENT is even or missing.  The second expression, `(PATIENT = .)`, will be true when PATIENT is missing.  So a result of 2 means that PATIENT is missing a result of 1 means that PATIENT is even and a result of 0 means that patient is odd.

So you could rewrite the case statement as:

```
CASE WHEN MISSING(PATIENT) then 'Error'
     WHEN MOD(PATIENT,2)=1 then 'Med A'
     ELSE 'Med B'
END AS DOSEGRP
```